# Can we import pg_dump from PostgreSQL 9.5 into 9.4.5

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5, downgrade

I am new to PostgreSQL.

I have a PostgreSQL 9.4.5 database set up on my machine and there I have imported a lot of tables.

I want to add one more database to it. So I have taken the dump of that database from one of the existing PostgreSQL on a VM.

I have the suspicion that the VM from which the dump has been taken has PostgreSQL version 9.5, and the VM to which I want to import has 9.4.5 .

I had a personal VM where I also had PostgreSQL 9.4.5 and there for testing I tried to import a PostgreSQL 9.5 dump.

There I got an error

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "row_security"
```

Now I figured it is because of the statement

```
SET row_security = off;
```

inside my backup file. I tried once more removing this line from the backup file and creating one more test DB on my testing VM. Then I didn't get the above error.

So I have doubt that should I be removing such lines and using the back up or it can have some bad effects also so I should not be doing so.

Comment: Sir, can you please tell me how can I use the 9.4 pg_Dump to create a dump from 9.5 database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You cannot dump a PostgreSQL database with a `pg_dump` from a lower version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to “downgrade” a PostgreSQL database.

You would have to edit the dump with a text editor and adapt everything that is supported in 9.5 but not in 9.4, just like you did. There is no better way to do it.

For example, the `row_security` parameter was introduced in 9.5, so you'd have to remove it.

If your 9.5 database uses some feature not available in 9.4, you are in trouble.